# Define shorthand command

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, shorthands

I use a lot of times the following code:

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
Math here
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
```

Is there a way to define a new shorthand command like the following:

```
\SC
{
Math here
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: (a) you should not use `align*` within `gather`, either use `align*` directly or use `aligned` inside the `gather`.  (b) see the amsmath documentation `texdoc amsmath` on why you should not do this, and how to do it if your really really have to.

Comment: That is not a particularly good idea. Makes the code a lot harder to read. Consider using a better editor, perhaps one that can give you that construction as a template. BTW: why `align*` as the inner construction and not just `aligned`. Do many people it may be quite confusing to see people use an 'outer' env used inside another 'outer' env

Comment: Sorry that is what I am using I just forgot it here in the MWE. I will edit it.

Comment: @daleif I don't really care about code readability. I want to be able to take notes fast.

Comment: You can't use  `align*` within `gather`. You have to use `aligned` instead. Wouldn't such a request rather be satisfied through the editor?

Comment: @adam,trust me you will regret it later on. My recommendation still stand, use an editor that can provide templates just by using a few key strokes.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what do you mean?

Comment: @daleif generally I agree with you. But I want to see how is this possible to be achieved and I like shorthand commands. Generally I don't use a lot in a certain project so there is no problem concerning code readability. Is there any other problem except that by using defined commands?

Comment: @Adam, perhaps straight LaTeX isn't the best format for taking fast notes. It is designed for carefully writing high-quality documents

Comment: @vonbrand I like having good quality notes and furthermore there are a lot of people taking notes in LaTeX. Also taking in accounts that I type fast and that my notes are mostly mathematics then you can see that it is the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article} % this must go first, there are many different classes
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\gathlign[1]%
{\begin{gather}\begin{aligned}#1 \end{aligned}\end{gather}}

\begin{document}

\gathlign{
  a & =  b + c \\
  a²   & = b²  + c² 
 }%

\end{document}
```

[image]

However I think  as @daleif: with a good editor you can get `\begin{gather}\begin{aligned} … \end{aligned}\end{gather}` and the cursor placed just in the middle within one shortcut. That would be still faster than typing a command!

Comment: Thank you I will try it! May I ask what is the purpose of the `%` in the end of `gathlign[1]` and in the end of `gathlign{}`? Also  why did you use the `*` in the definition of the new command?

Comment: Oh! It's to prevent  the insertion of a spurious space by TeX: it will not read anything on the lin paste %. Incidentally, it's also to prevent my editor to wrap text at that place. Not sure it's useful here, though — just an old habit. The * indicates it's a command with an argument that must not make more than the (TeX) line, i.e. must not contains any `\\` nor `\ par`.